# Unable To Compile And Use Erlang Port Driver Example From Docs

Tags: erlang

I have directly copy-pasted the code from the Erlang Docs provided in this [link](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html).

At the end of the page they have used the following command to compile

`gcc -o exampledrv -fpic -shared complex.c port_driver.c`

But the compiler was unable to find the header `erl_driver.h`, so I proceeded to compile with
`gcc -o exampledrv -fpic -shared complex.c port_driver.c -I/usr/local/lib/erlang/usr/include -L -lerl_driver` which compiled without any errors; but I am unable to run `compex5 : start("./exampledrv").`; because the shared library is unable to load successfully.

I'm currently using Erlang Version:17

Is there something wrong with code itself or is my method of compilation wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the file `exampledrv.so` from just `exampledrv` and
added the following lines of code in my start function to solve the problem:

`code:add_path("/home/nihal/Documents/Erlang/C/Fresh/driver/"),`

`DriverPath = "/home/nihal/Documents/Erlang/C/Fresh/driver/",`

These lines were added before I loaded the shared lib.

```
start(SharedLib) ->

    code:add_path("/home/nihal/Documents/Erlang/C/Fresh/driver/"),
    DriverPath = "/home/nihal/Documents/Erlang/C/Fresh/driver/",        
    case erl_ddll:load_driver(DriverPath, SharedLib) of
    ok -> ok;
    {error, already_loaded} -> ok;
    _ ->        
     exit({error, could_not_load_driver})
    end,
    spawn(?MODULE, init, [SharedLib]).
```

Reference: [this blog](http://blog.bugsense.com/post/24966013826/small-tips-when-you-are-building-erlang-drivers).

Answer (score 0):

Seems your library is not in common library directories. So you should include the path to its folder into environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can do in shell

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library/dir
```

And then start your application in the same shell. Also you can add this line to your /etc/profile or ~/.bashrc and the variable will be assigned automatically each time when you launch shell.

Or you can launch your port that way

```
start("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library/dir ./exampledrv")
```